# Don't execute Next javascript Function if First One is Executed in OnClick()

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

I am very weak in JavaScript.
Actually I am using two function as onclick:

```
onClick="check('owfy_email','owfy_email2'); return checkval() ;"
```

`check(a,b)` function is to check if the both email address and verify email address fields have same values while `checkval()` function look for other errors

For function `check(a,b)` I am using a code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(a,b) {
var obja = document.getElementById(a)
var objb = document.getElementById(b)
if (obja.value==objb.value) {}
else {alert("The e-mail fields aren't the same!!")}
}
</script>
```

To pop up an error message if field values doesn't match.

But what happens, after the pop up message the next function executes and form processes to the next page. whereas I want that if pop up message come then user may get a chance to enter the emails again and form may only process when both email fields are same

**Note:** I have no access to `checkval()` function but can update `check(a,,b)` function easily.

Comment: why can't you modify checkval()? if you really can't, you can redefine checkval inside check() and make it an empty function but i don't think that will help.

Comment: If you can't change `checkval()`, why not modify `check(a, b)` to call `checkval()` when `obja.value==objb.value` is true?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false from your checkval() function or just return it at the end like so:

```
onClick="check('owfy_email','owfy_email2'); return checkval(); return false;"
```

Comment: Thank You troy!
I tried that but that didn't worked.

Is there some way to do like


`<script type="text/javascript">`

`function check(a,b) {`

`var obja = document.getElementById(a)`

`var objb = document.getElementById(b)`

`if (obja.value==objb.value) {}`

`else {alert("The e-mail fields aren't the same!!"); return false;}`

`}`

`</script>`



I mean I want to stop the script when it pop ups the warning message.

Comment: You can; the only requirement is that the last function being called in the onClick handler returns false;

Comment: Also, I would probably take Parv's approach above and put all of your logic into one function to make it more maintainable. Then you can make a single call like: onClick="return validateAllFields();". validateAllFields() would contain all of your validation logic before you submit the form. If anything is wrong, return false; otherwise, return true at the end of the function.

Comment: I modified `check(a,b)` to call `checkval()` when `obja.value==objb.value` is true and `return false`  in the `else` statement. And things started working perfectly.
You helped me a lot to get this,
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Make the 1st function (check) return false when the validation failed.
in onclick event, do this,

```
onclick="if(check('owfy_email','owfy_email2')){checkVal()};"
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to Troys ans.. i think you should modify your `check()` function a bit
and call the `checkval()` function fro within `check()` function

```
function check(a,b) {
var obja = document.getElementById(a)
var objb = document.getElementById(b)

//so modify the function so that
if(some_value)
{
//call the checkval() function
var r = checkval();
//check the return type of the checkval() function
if(r){return true;}
else
return false;
}

if (obja.value==objb.value) {}
else {
alert("The e-mail fields aren't the same!!");
}
}
```